# Error: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm busy writing a .NET Data Provider in C# as .NET counterpart of our Java JDBC Driver. This driver must connect over TCP/IP using XDR (Old marshaling protocol) to our RulesService. The JDBC Driver is working fine but the first prototype of C# gave me the error "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine".

It took me 2 days to find the solution: Use `System.IO.BufferedStream`!

E.g.:

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

socket.SendTimeout = timeout;
socket.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;

socket.SendBufferSize = 1048510;
socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 1048510;

socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
socket.NoDelay = true;

socket.Connect(host, port);

this.datastream = new **BufferedStream**((Stream)new NetworkStream(socket), 1048510);
```

Hope this post helps somebody to not spend 2 days searching for a solution :-)

Comment: Post the solution as the answer and accept it ;)

Comment: You really should post your solution as an answer, as walther suggested. [Posting question and answering it yourself is encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/), but you shouldn't post your solution in the question, because this way, the “question” looks like it's unanswered and it's not really a question.

Comment: Oke sorry didn't see the "Answer your own Question" option.

Comment: This isn't a question...